# Climb a tree or climb over a tree?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What's the difference between them?
Example: A fallen tree blocked the path and we had to climb over it.
Why can't we say "climb it" in this sentence.

Comment: You can certainly say that if you wish, but it will cause confusion, because "climb a tree" means to ascend up the branches of the tree.

Comment: Agreed, @Hot Licks. ‘Climbing’ implies ascending a vertical thing, while ‘climbing over’ implies getting over a horizontal obstacle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Climb a tree" means that you are going up into the tree.  Generally this means you're sitting in the branches for some period of time.

"Climb over a tree" means you climb the tree and then come down the other side.  I've only seen this used idiomatically if a tree has fallen into a path and you must climb it to keep traveling down your path.

Comment: You would probably say 'climb over a tree trunk', or 'climb over a fallen tree'.

Comment: "Climb over a treec" almost makes it clear that the tree is fallen.  You cannot climb over a standing tree unless it is tiny.